# How does nginx proxy pass works for nested paths?

Tags: nginx, proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, proxypass

I'm try to send the following over to a different node with the nested path

```
server_name http://cloudflare.myserver.com
location /api/client {
  proxy_pass http://cloudflare.anotherserver.com
}
```

How can I forward the request

> http://cloudflare.myserver.com/api/client/users/1

to

> http://cloudflare.anotherserver.com/users/1

notice the `users/1` needed to be forwarded also.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [docs](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass):

> If the proxy_pass directive is specified with a URI, then when a
>   request is passed to the server, the part of a normalized request URI
>   matching the location is replaced by a URI specified in the directive

So your location block needs to look like this:

```
location /api/client/ {
  proxy_pass http://cloudflare.anotherserver.com/;
}
```